# Angular 2 - Click event on changing array

Tags: arrays, angular, dynamic, click, ngfor

Currently I'm trying to learn some more about Angular 2 by creating the amazing one of a kind shopping list application. However got stuck on creating a `click` event on my search results.

*view.html*

```
<form class="search">

    <input type="text" name="query" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="query" (ngModelChange)="change()" (blur)="onBlur()" />

    <ul class="results" [class.hidden]="!showResults">

        <li *ngFor="let result of results">
            <a (click)="selectResult(result)">
                {{ result.title }}
            </a>
        </li>

    </ul>

</form>
```

*view.ts*

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'search',
  templateUrl: 'app/search/view.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/search/view.css']
})

export class Search
{

    ... Some interesting things here

    // selectResult
    // ------------------------------ -->

    selectResult (selected: any)
    {

        console.log(123);

    }

    // ------------------------------ -->

    ... More interesting things here

}
```

When someone starts typing the results will change dynamically. When someone clicks on a result nothing happens, no `console.log(123)`.

Anyone knows how to attach `click` to a `ngFor` that changes?

Answer (score 0):

You forget about one little thing, namely remove default href action. In your HTML file:

```
<a href="#" (click)="selectResult($event, result)">
   {{ result.title }}
</a>
```

and in your TypeScript file:

```
selectResult (event: any, selected: any) {
   event.preventDefault();
   console.log(123);
}
```

I hope that it will help.

Comment: Not working :( I've read the problem is because the results change and it cannot bind, but I don't believe that (this is Angular not jQuery :P).

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this problem.

Somehow the `click` event is not bound when you hide the element. (wtf...?)

This is the final solution:

*view.html*

```
<form class="search">

    <input type="text" name="query" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="query" (ngModelChange)="change()" (blur)="onBlur()" />

    {{ results.length }}

    <ul class="results" *ngIf="results.length != 0">

        <li *ngFor="let result of results">
            <a href="#" (click)="selectResult(result)">
                {{ result.title }}
            </a>
        </li>

    </ul>

</form>
```